# Smartgwt DataSource with gwt requestfactory etc

Tags: gwt, datasource, smartgwt, requestfactory

Does anyone have a working example of using the new GWT constructs for `RequestFactory` with a SmartGWT DataSource for databound widgets ?

If possible I would like to make a generic data service that contains methods for `listAll`, `getByExample`, `getByPrimaryKey` etc. I beleibe it should be possible ???

If using `RequestFactory` would it make sense to ditch the datasource altogether and work directly with the widget fields ?

Cheers,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=10850&highlight=GwtRPCDatasource

This link provides an implementation of smartgwt datasource with RPC. My take is it should be easy to extend it to RequestFactory.

About ditching DataSource, I would advice against it. I have created an application with it and trust me, smartgwt widgets are very deeply ingrained with a datasource. A lot of vanilla functionality of the widgets depends on datasource. To ditch the datasouce all together and try and use the widgets gets pretty complicated. I always have felt that smartgwt skimps on documentation, and that will hit you hard.

So prefer a datasource unless you have a very gooood understanding of how smartgwt works!

Comment: Stiking with the DataSource. Currently struggling with RequestCatory and generics. Not sure if it will play nicely !

Comment: It should. Its a good initiative. Do search the net for some samples. And let me know if you get stuck. This will be a good initiative.. and a great learning experience for you.